# How to reach an array by name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 arrays like this:

```
var windows_array = [];
var google_array = [];
```

Here, I want in reach to specified array in function by passing network.

```
function add_friends(network, friend){
    (network + '_array').push(friend);
}

function get_friends(network){
    var d = $('.div_out');
    for(var i=0; i< (network + '_array').Length; i++){
        d.append('<div>' + (network + '_array')[i].name + '</div>')
    }
}
```

My question here is how I can do it in jQuery?

I know that in PHP it is possible.

Comment: use if-else if you have only 2 arrays

Comment: Any time you find yourself wanting to identify a variable via dynamically referencing its name at runtime, there is probably a better solution.  In the case of Javascript, that solution is usually an object, whose keys can be dynamic without having to resort to `eval`.  In general, `eval` is to be avoided as inefficient and prone to security/reliability issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare the arrays inside an object like this:

```
var reg = {
    'windows': [],
    'google': []
};
```

And then, change the code to subscript the `reg` object:

```
function add_friends(network, friend) {
    reg[network].push(friend);
}

function get_friends(network)
{
    var $container = $('.div_out');

    $.each(reg[network], function() {
        $('<div>', { text: this.name }).appendTo($container);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your solution is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Use switch case:

```
   switch(network) {
        case google:
            google_array.push(friend);
            break;
        case windows:
            windows_array.push(friend);
            break;
        default:
            --
        --
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The *not so elegant* solution:

```
 var t = eval(network + '_array');
 t.push(friend);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RpLF3/)

Comment: This was the originally accepted answer. Some members decided to bash it because they are afraid of using `eval`